# Mann-Whitney U Test with SciPy

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, scipy

I would like to compare two datasets. Each dataset includes the ratio of chosen features (number of chosen tokens/number of all tokens in the document). The distribution is not normal.

I want to check of one group uses the features more often than the other one.

Would the Mann-Whitney U Test be suitable for me in this case? Which alternative should I take (SciPy suggests two-sided, less, and greater alternative)?

Comment: What question(s) do you have of your data?

Comment: Do you want to estimate stochastic dominance between the two datasets using MWU test? Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/533424/which-form-of-stochastic-dominance-is-tested-for-using-the-mann-whitney-u-hypoth

Comment: I want to check if one group uses selected features more often than the other one